# Creating hidden text (and then subsequently showing it) in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the atoms tab of my Periodic Alchemy game, I have dropdowns that allow users to select how many protons, neutrons, and electrons they want in their atom. If a user strikes upon a certain atom, say, hydrogen, (1 Proton, 1 Neutron, 1 Electron), then the text "Hydrogen: 1" should appear signifying that you've discovered Hydrogen. Unfortunately, I can't find anything in the Bootstrap Information website: getboostrap.com 
Other than Modals, which didn't suit my needs. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bootstrap feature. You can hide text with the CSS: `display: none;`. You can show it with the jQuery `.show()`.

Comment: This doesn't really help me if I don't know the script on how to use it. Could you add it?

Answer (score 0):

Does that fit your needs?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrwj5/)**

HTML:

```
<select class="selection" id="protons">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="selection" id="neutrons">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="selection" id="electrons">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div class="atom hide" data-protons="1" data-neutrons="1" data-electrons="1">Hydrogen</div>
<div class="atom hide" data-protons="1" data-neutrons="1" data-electrons="2">Whatever</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.selection').change(function() {
    $('.atom').addClass('hide');
    $('.atom[data-protons=' + $('#protons').val() + '][data-neutrons=' + $('#neutrons').val() + '][data-electrons=' + $('#electrons').val() + ']').removeClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use the script you gave me at the bottom. Do I put the values in the ".val()"?

Comment: You mean what to do when a user "found" an atom?